# why does this program replace all characters with 'a'

Tags: c++, arrays, char

In the program I have a char array. It gets input from the user who enters characters and when the letter b is entered, it should  replace it with the letter a. On the contrary, it is replacing all the elements with the letter a instead of just replacing the letter b with an a. Why is it doing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int buff_len = 10;
char buffer [buff_len];

for(int i = 0; i < buff_len; i++){
        cin >> buffer[i];

}

for(int j = 0; j < buff_len; j++){
    if(buffer[j] = 'b'){
        buffer[j] = 'a';
    }

}

for(int i = 0; i < buff_len; i++){
    cout << buffer[i];
}


system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have three answers, but I have a question for you: Why haven't you enabled compiler warnings or (in case you have) why did you ignore them? (Or are there *still* compilers out there that don't give a warning on this??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `==` to compare.

The `=` is the assigning operator.

What you're doing is always assigning `'a'` to `buffer[j]` since `if(buffer[j] = 'b')` is always evaluated to *true*.

**Why?**

*The expression of the assignment returns the assigned value, in this case `if(buffer[j] = 'b')` will be always true, that's why the code below the if-statement is always executed.*

Comment: I should had known this. I don't know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try update:

```
if(buffer[j] = 'b'){
```

to:

```
if(buffer[j] == 'b')
             ^^^
```

Because `if(buffer[j] = 'b')` will always be evaluated to true, that's why below statement is always executed.

```
buffer[j] = 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparisions == is required. `buffer[j] = 'b'` (an assignment) will always be true.

```
if(buffer[j] == 'b')
```

Answer (score 0):

because the `buffer[j] = 'b'` has return value which always equals true.